# Class variables lookup vs instance variables lookup

Tags: python, instance-variables, class-variables

I have a class which contains a number of **class variables**:

`c_dict1`, `c_dict2`, `c_dict3`

They  are all dictionaries, and store some values using some of the instance variables below as keys.

I have *a few hundreds* of instances of this class, and each has the following **instance variables**:

`i_key1`, `i_key2`, `i_key3`, `i_attr1`, `i_attr2`, `i_attr3`

They first three (`i_key*`) can be used to look up the latter three (`i_attr*`) in the class variables. In other words:

```
self.i_attr1 = MyClass.c_dict1(i_key1)
self.i_attr2 = MyClass.c_dict2(i_key2)
self.i_attr3 = MyClass.c_dict3(i_key3)
```

My question is:

In terms of performance, should I maintain the instance variables `i_attr*` locally, or should I access them via dictionary lookup using class variables `c_dict*`? Obviously, doing via the class variables get rid of three pointers per instance, which may save some memory, but is there any significant speed penalty for doing it this way?

Comment: I find quite strange your "scenario". Are you sure you're doing this in the right way? Isn't there a simpler way of doing what you're trying to do?

Comment: I think we need to know the purpose of your program.  What is `MyClass`? What do the `i_key`s, `i_attr`s, and `c_dict`s represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In terms of performance, should I maintain the instance variables i_attr* locally, or should I access them via dictionary lookup using class variables c_dict*?

If this sort of constant-time micro-optimisation is important and not premature, probably don't use python.

I strongly suspect that this is premature optimisation, and you have not identified this as a hotpot, because if you had, you could just profile your code both ways, and wouldn't be asking here.

You can get much more of a speedup by worrying about your architecture, whether you should be running a long-lived process which can take advantage of PyPi, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer to your question in terms of performance as it depends on the frequency of access and how you use the results, you just have to try and see. Run your code with `timeit` or `profile` to see the results.

If you want to keep the `c_dictN` in sync with `i_attrN`, it is probably better to use something like:

```
self.i_attrN = property(lambda self:       MyClass.c_dictN[i_keyN], 
                        lambda self, val:  MyClass.c_dictN[i_keyN] = val)
```

(note that you can also use `setattr` and `getattr` to set all fields in a loop if they are really named like your example).

If you can do like the above, and you can change the contract of your class, another solution would be to use an indexed accessor like:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    return MyClass.c_dict[idx][self.i_key[idx]]

def __setitem__(self, idx, val):
    MyClass.c_dict[idx][self.i_key[idx]] = val
```

Then you could change the access from

```
a = myobj.i_attrN
myobj.i_attrN = b
```

to

```
a = myobj[N]
myobj[N] = b
```

Comment: I should probably add that all instance variables `i_attr*` are set once when initializing (no change afterwards), and all subsequent accesses to them are internal. Would that make any difference?

Comment: Then I think your difference is one hash lookup vs two. In any case the impact would be minimal.